# Modifying x tick label for date in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to modify the format of the x-tick label to date format (%Y-%m-%d) on this [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB41k.jpg).

However if I run this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

plt.plot(x_new['t1'], 'r', x_new['t2'], 'b', x_new['t3'], 'b')

mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
plt.xticks(rotation = 25)

plt.title('Time Series Graph')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Values')

plt.show()
```

The tick label is shown as time format (click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8a5S.jpg)).

Does anyone have the solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the date formatter to the xaxis.

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%y-%m-%d'))
```